# Setting up a git repo with Eclipse based LPCXpresso IDE

Tags: eclipse, git, lpc

I am working on a multi-developer project on an ARM M0 microcontroller.  While I really would like to get this working with linux GNU tools, that is not an option.  All of us must use the Eclipse based LPCXpresso IDE for development.  We have made attempts in the past to set up a git repo, but it ends up being broken in one way or another when trying to clone that repo out to multiple computers, Windows and Mac.  We are currently passing around zipfiles created by the "Export" function of the IDE.

The workspace has four "Resources," "Projects," I am not sure what these are actually called, I don't use Eclipse much at all. These four "Projects" must be all added to the same repo, and be able to work on each developer's workspace.

Any attempts of this in the past have left the repo with hardcoded paths, incomplete "Projects," and other anomalies that I don't recall at the moment.

Has any one dealt with this particular IDE and setting up a git repo for it?  I've tried following some tutorials on setting up a git repo with Eclipse workspaces/projects and was unsuccessful.  Does anyone have a tutorial for setting this up?

Comment: Is the problem about the project settings ? 
You should add to the git repo just the source files. The project file should be created separatly on each computers... Or maybe I didn't understant ?

Comment: I suppose that would be possible, but it is still a headache to get each person up and running.  I want to know if its possible to git the whole workspace, ignore generated files and such; so then each person can clone, point LPCXpresso to the git dir as the workspace, and then begin work immediately without having to set up details of the project on each computer.

Comment: To continue my last thought.  This is why we have been using zipfiles, its easy to import/export through LPCXpresso, and already has set up the details to just click debug/build/etc. and have it work.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse/LPCxpresso support EGIT plugin which is a integrated plugin for adding version control feature to your IDE,
We was in same situation with Lpcxpresso and using egit completely covered our need.Also you can use a free non open-source repository host (like Microsoft TFS) as your on-line repository.